# Cannot set microsecond value from Java to the Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, timestamp, xmlgregoriancalendar

I have a date which created from current time and the object type is XMLGregorianCalendar. In Java, I can see that my date has microseconds but in the SQL, it is set as 0. What is the exact problem here?

```
    public static XMLGregorianCalendar initializeTime(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        try {
            XMLGregorianCalendar time= DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
              .newXMLGregorianCalendar(String.valueOf
              (LocalDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MICROS)));
            
        return time;
        } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException var3) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Execution time could not created.");
        }
    }
```

In Java it shows: 2023-05-24T15:50:07.931456

But in the SQL (the type is TIMESTAMP(6)) it shows like this : 24-MAY-23 15.50.07.931000000 PM

SQL calling, you can find it down below.
dummytest is a procedure basically taking a param and inserting this param into a table.

```
<select id="add_time" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="java.util.Map">
        {call dummytest(
                #{time, mode=IN, jdbcType=TIMESTAMP}
            )}
    </select>
```

procedure code:

```
create or replace procedure dummytest(p_timestamp TIMESTAMP) is
begin
  insert into testtimestamp values (p_timestamp);
  commit;
end ;
```

I am losing the microsecond precision. I have to use XMLGregorianCalendar because all code designed for this API.

Comment: How did you declare the timestamp column in SQL?   Just `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: It looks like your column might be defined as `TIMESTAMP(3)` - if you don't have the DDL you can check that in `user_tab_columns` or `all_tab_columns`.

Comment: What *exactly* is the data type of your column? Voting to close for insufficient information.

Comment: Why involve the legacy class `XMLGregorianCalendar`?

Comment: I cannot imagine a case where calling `LocalDateTime.now()` is the right thing to do. That class lacks the context of a time zone or offset, so it cannot represent a point on the timeline.

Comment: I do not know who voted for closing this question but I couldnt check the answer. As I said I declared as TIMESTAMP(6).

Comment: @BasilBourque can I ask what is the reason to vote for closure? Please read the question carefully next time.

Comment: Your Question has many issues. For one: You speak of output from Java, and output from the database, but you do not show code for either. For another: you include some needlessly convoluted code with `XMLGregorianCalendar` that is likely irrelevant to your issue.

Comment: It is a bit disingenuous to accuse Basil of not reading the question.  We can read the edit history to see where and when you edited the question to respond to his comments.

Comment: I shared the code that I am using the java. I added sql mapping and calling now. If you specify, I can share the what you need.

Comment: The next step would be to also post the code of the `dummytest` procedure. Also, I'm not too familiar with jdbcType Timestamp but the docs at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/Timestamp.html suggest that the resolution is milliseconds at best.

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk thanks for your kind message. Unfortunately in my case, I need microseconds.

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk also added the code of dummytest procedure.

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk I don’t know whether it’s relevant.  From your doc link: *... the ability to hold the SQL `TIMESTAMP` fractional seconds value, by allowing the specification of fractional seconds to a precision of nanoseconds.* However the `java.sql.Timestamp` class is outdated and should not be used provided that Oracle is offering a JDBC 4.2 compliant driver allowing to use `LocalDateTime` (also offering nanosecond precision).

Comment: In the declaration of the stored procedure, in `dummytest(p_timestamp TIMESTAMP)` it does not say `TIMESTAMP(6)`. Might this be the issue??

Comment: @OleV.V. In PLSQL procedure declaration you cannot specify length. such as varchar2(100), timestamp(6), etc.

Comment: Thanks for your additions, I'm afraid I can't help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed by custom handler in java side.

```
<select id="add_time" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="java.util.Map">
        {call dummytest(
                #{time, mode=IN, jdbcType=TIMESTAMP, typeHandler = com.project.yunus.XMLGregorianCalendarWithFractionalTypeHandler}
            )}
    </select>
```

Content of XMLGregorianCalendarWithFractionalTypeHandler:

```
public class XMLGregorianCalendarWithFractionalTypeHandler implements TypeHandler {
    public XMLGregorianCalendarWithFractionalTypeHandler() {
    }

    public void setParameter(PreparedStatement paramPreparedStatement, int paramInt, Object paramObject, JdbcType paramJdbcType) throws SQLException {
        if (paramObject == null) {
            paramPreparedStatement.setNull(paramInt, 93);
        } else {
            if (!(paramObject instanceof XMLGregorianCalendar)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Excepted XMLGregorianCalendar, but have: " + paramObject);
            }

            XMLGregorianCalendar objectCalendar = ((XMLGregorianCalendar)paramObject);
            Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(objectCalendar.toString().replace("T", " "));
            paramPreparedStatement.setTimestamp(paramInt, timestamp);
        }

    }

    public Object getResult(ResultSet rs, String columnLabel) throws SQLException {
        Timestamp value = rs.getTimestamp(columnLabel);
        return rs.wasNull() ? null : stringToXMLGregorianCalendar(value);
    }

    public Object getResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        Timestamp value = rs.getTimestamp(columnIndex);
        return rs.wasNull() ? null : stringToXMLGregorianCalendar(value);
    }

    public Object getResult(CallableStatement rs, int columnNb) throws SQLException {
        Timestamp value = rs.getTimestamp(columnNb);
        return rs.wasNull() ? null : stringToXMLGregorianCalendar(value);
    }

    private static XMLGregorianCalendar stringToXMLGregorianCalendar(Timestamp value) {
        try {
            return dateToXMLGregorianCalendar(value);
        } catch (Exception var2) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static XMLGregorianCalendar dateToXMLGregorianCalendar(Timestamp timestamp) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
        return  DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(timestamp.toString().replace(" ", "T"));

    }
```